# View an object returned by an API call using javascript

Tags: javascript

I realize that this is a very basic question (and I'm sure it will be downvoted, as many of my questions are), but I cannot get an answer that I readily understand from the internet.

If I create an object in the browser console,

```
   var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"};
```

then when I type "person" in the console, the object is recalled:

```
   {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
```

My question is if I have a URL that executes an API call, and that API returns an object, how can I make that call and view that object in the console?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the "done" handler of your AJAX call do a console.log(result) - see this jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pfmbxnpe/:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "URL",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {}
}).then(function(serverResult) {
    console.log(serverResult);
});
```

Comment: @bloomers - sorry I used "then" instead of "done" in the example above (I could've used .done but chose not to). Anyhow, the function passed into the ".then" function call will execute after the server responds and will pass back the result of the API call (the object - "serverResult" in the example above)

Comment: @bloomers I've updated my post with a link to a live example

Comment: I pasted this into the console, replacing "URL" with my API URL, and received "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at <anonymous>:1:3". How can I get my browser to recognize jQuery?

Comment: @bloomers try making a test page (test.html):
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
   $.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: 'GET'
   }).then(function(serverResult) {
    console.log(serverResult);
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: I did this. Replacing with my own URL, it returns "{state: ƒ, always: ƒ, catch: ƒ, pipe: ƒ, then: ƒ, …}", followed by an error "405 (Method not allowed)". I then replaced with your URL from jsfiddle and received "{state: ƒ, always: ƒ, catch: ƒ, pipe: ƒ, then: ƒ, …}", followed by two errors: "net::ERR_ABORTED" and "Failed to load:  The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."